# Built-in functions for 3d calculations

Tags: c#, 3d

In my current project, I need to do some calculations in 3d space, like calculating intersection points of lines with planes, determining if a point is inside a triangle / rectangle / (flat) polygon etc.

The `Systems.Windows.Media.Media3D` namespace offers some functionality for those purposes like cross and dot products of 3d vectors. Sadly, I cannot find good tutorials on the functionality of that namespace - most tutorials deal with drawing which is not relevant for me. Just from intellisense, it is hard to figure out what's available, and some methods are static instead of instance methods (e.g. `Point3D.Substract`). And many Google searches point to functionality of the Xna namespace - which seems unavailable on Windows 8 / 10.

Are there other "common" namespaces in the .Net framework for such calculations?

Or do you know good tutorials for calculations with Media3d?

Of course, I could write my own library for that, but that feels like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: For points inside rectangle the `Rect3D` has some methods if i recall but in general don't expect much from `Media3D` namespace in terms of 3d calculation. It has very small objects that are perfect to hold data and transfer over different system as compared to third party 3d engine objects.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Media3d, but in general try searching for Raytracer + C#. I'm sure you can find opensource project that do what you are requiring.

Answer (score 0):

On CodeProject, someone pointed me to MathNet.Spatial (http://spatial.mathdotnet.com/). Their library contains some useful functions for my purpose, but there are many functions which I still have to write myself. So further suggestions are welcome.